# How many possible casts of $9$ dice are possible with at least one $5$ or at least one $1$ or both?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many possible casts of $9$ dice are possible with at least one $5$ or at least one $1$ or both?

I think it is a multicombination for all possible casts of dice. There have to be subtracted the casts that do not contain any $5$ and the casts that do not contain any $1$. With the inclusion-exclusion-principle I have have added then the casts that do not contain any $5$ neither any $1$.

$|$MComb_9$([1,6])| -2 \cdot |$MComb$_9([1,5])|+|$MComb$_9([1,4])|$

$= \binom{6+9-1}{6-1} -2 \cdot \binom{5+6-1}{5-1} + \binom{9+4-1}{4-1}$

$= \binom{14}{5} -2 \cdot \binom{10}{4} + \binom{12}{3}$

$= 1802$

Unfortunately this is the wrong solution. The correct solution is $1782$.

**Question**: What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake is that your method actually counts all the ways that have **both** at least one $1$ and at least one $5$. (There is an extra error that the middle term should then be $-2\binom{13}4$; the actual number with both is $792$.)

The correct method is just to take all ways minus the number of ways to have neither, i.e. $\binom{14}5-\binom{12}3=1782$.